# \curl ... | bash ... what's the slash for?

Tags: bash, shell

looking at the magic installers which appear for all types of projects (e.g. for rvm) you'll always see commands like:

```
\curl ... | bash
```

e.g.

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

And I was wondering why these commands start with a slash - they seem to run fine without it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the duplicate?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is used to call the "original" command, avoiding it to be called with the possible aliases. That is, disables the possible aliases on the command `curl` and adjusts to the original one.

If you have

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

and then you do `grep`, it will have colours. So if you do not want colours, you would just write `\grep`.

Comment: Thanks ... simple when you know it but impossible to find via Google ;)

Comment: it will call the original command ONLY if there is no function with the same name. Please see my answer for the alias/function/command order of evaluation by bash  (In a nutshell: `\something` : will only avoid the alias, but will not bypass a function.   `command something` : will bypass the alias AND the function and launch the command "something")

Comment: This is an interesting point, @OlivierDulac. I found quite several options in a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6162903/1983854 . Following your example, yes, `\something` just bypasses the alias, not the possible functions with this name. To do so, `$(which command)`, `"command"`, can work.

Comment: @fedorqui: or the (bash internal) `command` keyword can too. As in : `command thecommand`.  See my answer ^^

Comment: @pagid I actually found this using Google: why "\curl"

Answer (score 24):

it's a backslash

it is to start the command starting with that name (OR the function) but not the ALIAS.

To make sure to bypass both **function** AND **alias** :

```
command somecommand
```

To bypass **just the alias** (and thus launch a function, or if no function, the command):

```
\somecommand
```

Let's see which takes precedence over which (I use bash 2.05b ... ymmv)

I'll define a function AND an alias with the same name as a command (ls) :

```
$ alias ls='echo A'
$ function ls { echo B ; }
```

Using "type -all ls" shows the order of evaluation :

```
$ type -all ls
ls is aliased to `echo A'
ls is a function
ls ()
{
    echo B
}
ls is /usr/bin/ls
```

But we can find out also by trying them out:

```
$ ls
A
$ \ls
B
$ command ls
file1 file2 file3
```

So it seems the order of precedence is : **alias** -before- **function** -before- **command taken in the path**. This is the order in bash (and the `command` command too.) - I noticed it differs in some other shells!

Of course, if you precise the relative/absolute path, it is then forced to be the command pointed at:

```
$ /usr/bin/ls
file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: note: the order I talk about is in bash (and the "command" command too.). I noticed it differs in some other shells!

Comment: And today I learned about the "command" keyword. After almost 2 decades of Unix/Linux shell usage.

Comment: @Perleone: there is always something new to discover or create, and that's why we love this ^^

Answer (score 3):

It bypasses a possible alias `curl`.