# What does it mean when a shell command starts with \

Tags: shell, curl

I found these command from http://rvm.io/rvm/install

Why do we need \ in the following command?

```
$\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Comment: "How to ignore aliases or functions when running a command?" -- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ignore-shell-aliases-functions-when-running-command/

Comment: Also note that piping anything directly into a shell is a **huge** security risk. You don't want to execute random commands without inspecting them first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version: This skips replacing "curl" with an alias you might have defined.

A more verbose answer you can find here: [\curl ... | bash ... what's the slash for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951772/curl-bash-whats-the-slash-for)