# Error while getting disk usage of a folder in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, du

I have `XYZ=/opt/Ind` and certain directories under `/opt/Ind`

I sorted the directories by : `ls -t $XYZ`
Then I need to get only the **size** of the first folder.
I tried

```
du -sk $(ls -t $XYZ/TAL/ | head -n 1)
```

It gives me this error

```
du: cannot access `\033[0m\033[01;34m20160525_033732\033[0m': No such file or directory
```

Will be glad for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not using the normal `ls` but an alias, so that it provides you some coloured output. This way, instead of a normal name `20160525_033732` you get it with the blue colour.

```
$ echo -e "\033[0m\033[01;34m20160525_033732\033[0m"
20160525_033732
```

Just use [`\ls` to use the original `ls` without any alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15951871/1983854).

```
du -sk "$(\ls -t $XYZ/TAL/ | head -n 1)"
#         ^
```

See what the alias is with:

```
type ls
```

It will probably return something like:

```
ls is aliased to `ls --color=always'
```

Comment: Can I print only the size and not the folder name with this command

Comment: @MohitArora sure. You can say `du file | awk '{print $1}'`.

Answer (score 0):

add `--color=never` to the ls so it won't colorize the output:

```
du -sk $(ls --color=never -t $XYZ/TAL/ | head -n 1)
```