# Home directory navigation in bash script

Tags: bash

I need a simple bash script function for .bashrc file to navigate to my home directory.
We use hg for all our work purpose in the directory and contains many streams.

```
/home/<username>/RelStream1/
/home/<username>/RelStream2/
/home/<username>/RelStream3/
/home/<username>/RelStream4/
```

For namesake i call this /home//RelStream1/ path as repo home.

Now for work purpose, i need to navigate to sub folders from my repo home path.
`/home/<username>/RelStream1/pkgdir/appsdir/moduledir/submoduledir/....`
After finishing work, i need to come back to home repo directory for compilation.
I have added alias like this, but still its painful to remember the path back.

```
    alias ..="cd .."
    alias ..2="cd ../.."
    alias ..3="cd ../../.."
    alias ..4="cd ../../../.."
    alias ..5="cd ../../../../.."
```

Please note many repo home directories would be used at any point of time and hence setting aliases as `alias rhome='cd /home/<username>/RelStreamX/'` will have little use.

I just need a simple bash function to get back to repo home directory (current repo).
It has to get the current path and navigate my directory back to home repo directory

```
    Ex1:
    From: /home/<username>/RelStream1/pkgdir/appsdir/moduledir/submoduledir/
    To: /home/<username>/RelStream1/ 

    Ex2:
    From: /home/<username>/RelStream3/pkgdir/appsdir/moduledir/submoduledir/micromodule/
    To: /home/<username>/RelStream3/ 

    Ex3:
    From: /home/<username>/RelStream4/pkgdir/appsdir/
    To: /home/<username>/RelStream4/
```

I have tried some methods in bash(beginner), but does not give expected results.

code:

```
    repohome_func()
    {
    cwd=$(pwd)
    echo "CurrPath:${cwd}"
    sep="/"

    //My plan is to search the cur path with "/" char up to 4 times, 
    //cut the front string and then execute that cmd. 

    }alias rhome=repohome_func
```

Comment: cd takes me to home directory, but it need to be taken to some other directory...Pls read my question

Comment: Have you tried `pushd pathToOtherFolder` and then `pop` when done?

Comment: Not yet but need to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should make:

```
alias rhome="cd $(pwd | sed 's~/[^/]*~~4g')"
```

It gets the current path with `pwd` and replaces it to what is needed. As this is within `$()` then we `cd` there.

You need to remove all current path but the first three blocks. With this `sed`, we do that.

See an example with a file:

```
$ cat a
/home/myuser/myrepo1/asld/as/asdf/asdf/asdf
/home/myuser/myrepo2/asdf
/home/myuser/myrepo3/asld/as/asdf/f/asdf
/home/myuser/myrepo4/asld/as/asdf/
$ sed 's~/[^/]*~~4g' a
/home/myuser/myrepo1
/home/myuser/myrepo2
/home/myuser/myrepo3
/home/myuser/myrepo4
```

From what was commented below, it seems like that the solution was not working as an alias, but it does as a function. The hypothesis is that there must be some alias in either `cd`, `pwd` or `sed` that makes them work differently.

As aliases are bypassed by functions, using it that way mades it. Otherwise, it could also work by using `\` before any command, so the command alias gets bypassed as well.

```
alias rhome="\cd $(\pwd | \sed 's~/[^/]*~~4g')"
```

More info:

- [Temporarily disabling an alias / quoting a word with a backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6162903/1983854)
- [\curl … | bash … what's the slash for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15951772/1983854).

Comment: I just want to try a cmd in bash prompt "rhome", then it should get me to current repo home directory. I don't want to be bothered with X.

Comment: For that, you just need an alias: `alias rhome="cd /your/needed/path"`. Apart from that, `X` is strictly needed, there is no way to indicate a variable behaviour without a variable.

Comment: I will be working on different repo directories at the same time. Hence that option will be applicable for one directory.

Comment: This solution does not work properly. It goes back to /home/<username>/ instead of /home/<username>/RelStream1/

Comment: @userm it can't be possible. This is keeping three blocks in the path.

Comment: I have provided the output obtained

alias rhme="cd $(pwd | sed 's~/[^/]*~~4g')"

[userm@TEGM001 ~]$ cd codebk/mur/mur2/
[userm@TEGM001 mur2]$ pwd
/home/userm/codebk/mur/mur2
[userm@TEGM001 mur2]$
[userm@TEGM001 mur2]$ rhme
[userm@TEGM001 ~]$ pwd
/home/userm

Comment: @userm it is not very clear to see code in comments. Could you edit your question adding this?

Comment: I have updated the output at the end of the question for your use

Comment: I got output of the command as given below
echo "$(pwd | sed 's~/[^/]*~~4g')" 
outputs as /home/mvenugop/codebk
May be the last "/" is missed

Comment: @userm I still don't understand it. `echo "/home/userm/codebk/mur/mur/" | sed 's~/[^/]*~~4g'` to me returns `/home/userm/codebk`. Give a try with `alias rhme="cd $(pwd | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} NF=4'`.

Comment: Was this your full command??
alias rhme2="cd $(pwd | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} NF=4'"
I get error as unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' and 
syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @userm ups, yes, it is like this --> `alias rhme="cd $(pwd | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} NF=4')"`

Comment: after you new cmd executing, i still the same result.

Comment: @userm I don't have an explanation for that and won't debug any more. Just try with `5` instead of `4` in both sed and awk commands.

Comment: Changed to 5 instead of 4, but still the same result.
May be there is some problem in my system.
Not sure, i will award for the effort spent for this question.

Comment: @userm I am thinking that your `cd` may have some alias. Type `alias cd` or diretly `alias` and see if it is hiding some problem there.

Comment: One good thing, if i executed your code within bash function, it works as expected.
repohome_func()
{
echo "$(pwd | sed 's~/[^/]*~~4g')"
cd $(pwd | sed 's~/[^/]*~~4g')
}
alias rhome=repohome_func

Comment: @userm Good one! Then there must be something in aliases bothering. You can bypass them with \ ([More info here on backslash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15951772/1983854)): `alias rhme="\cd $(\pwd | \sed 's~/[^/]*~~4g')"`. Also, the name of the function can be used directly. You can call `repohome_func` once you defined this function.

Comment: Dear downvoter: mind to explain the reason of the downvote? I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
function repohome() {
    local repodir=${PWD/$HOME\/}
    cd "$HOME/${repodir%%/*}"
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work properly. It goes back to /home/<username>/ instead of /home/<username>/RelStream1/

Comment: What version of bash are you using?

Comment: @userm: I just tested it on `bash 3.2.48` and `4.3.11` and it worked OK. Really weird that it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your home directory to the front of `CDPATH`, for example,

```
CDPATH=/home/<username>:.
```

then any relative path used with `cd` will be looked up first in your home directory before the current working directory. Then

```
cd Relstream1
```

will take you to `/home/<username>/Relstream1` before `./Relstream1`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but sill my intention is not to bother about current repo directory where i am working. It should automatically navigate back to current repo directory.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the builtin commands `pushd` and `popd`. If you use `pushd <dir>` instead of `cd <dir>`, you can then use `popd` to return to the previous working directory.